# django-registration with custom user

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

I have searched high and low and found no complete answers.  Nothing seems to work. I'm fairly new to django but it seems that what I'm doing should be fine.  I don't want to have my members sign up with a username.  I hate usernames.  Just the email address and password is needed.  So I'm forced to make a custom user (the way I understand it).  After that adjustment nothing seems to work.  I just want django-registration to accept my custom user but it can't.  I have tried a handful of forks on github that claim to have updated the registration to accept custom users.  They don't seem to work. My questions are:

What is a valid version of django-registration that allows for custom users?
How do you install that version?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in installing it...

I am able to log into my administration and I'm able to log into the user account that was created when I created my super user account (command line).  My only problem is that I am unable to sign up as a new user.  I'm just taken to the sign up page again after submitting.  If I don't fill in all the required sign up info I see the expected notices so the code is partially working.  The database doesn't show a new user either.  Hopefully someone can help me because I've been researching and trying new things for days.

Thanks

Comment: see [that](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/36/fixes-for-15-use-templateview-and-the-new/diff), django-registration dont support custom user.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply comment, but due to my lack of posting am unable. Anyways...

As lalo stated, django-registration doesn't really support custom users. You could try doing [this](https://bitbucket.org/prjts/django-registration/commits/ba31fc3053bfca7eb7a19d912882e50e295adc55). I added an extra field to my model and made those changes, which allow me to create users but failed to save the value of my extra field.

So I would say that custom users + django-registration can be done, but you will likely end up overriding many classes/methods provided in django-registration and thus it may be easier to try to create it all from scratch. That's my brief experience, at least.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I concluded.  Some of the "forks" that I have seen come close.  I may end up adjusting the fork you mentioned.  It seems that the custom user registration versions let you add fields along with the username field...  I could be wrong though.  I'm pretty new to django.